# Set Default Desktop Resolution {Windows 10}

Tags: windows-10, resolution, desktop

I have a Windows 10 laptop which off late has started behaving a bit oddly.

My desktop resolution on every restart changes to 1024 * 768 for some reason. I have a standard 1920 * 1080 display and I would like to be it that way. Every time it restarts it sets back to the old resolution.

Would like to know what can be done to set the default resolution back since there seems no explicit setting in the windows settings menu for this.

Device Specs:
HP 15 Series
Windows 10 Version 1909
OS.Build 18363.1139

Comment: Have you installed the latest BIOS and drivers? The computer "tells" the OS the specs of the hardware, so your problem isn't trying to set a "default" resolution, it is trying to get the OS to recognize the hardware it is running on properly, and you start doing this by making certain all of your drivers and firmware are completely up to date

Comment: @music2myear yes I updated my BIOS and Drivers. But it is still the same condition....

Comment: Have you tried a fresh Windows install, or at least a Windows repair? At this point you now need to try to isolate whether this is a hardware or a software issue. To fully determine that this is a software issue you will need to perform first a repair or refresh of Windows 10, and if that doesn't work, a full clean reinstall. If your system still doesn't properly recognize the hardware properly, your issue will be with the hardware.

Comment: @music2myear It is strange because nothing was wrong uptil two dates back, I even didn't get any updates recently. I also tried restoring registry since I backup on a daily basis. But nothing worked. Also I cannot do a fresh reinstall since this is a laptop. So I don't have any ISOs or something back here. Win10 was preinstalled.

Comment: Is there a way through the registry or powershell?

Comment: Please look up how Windows 10 is reinstalled and licensed. You don't need a CD drive, an ISO, or a license key if you bought the laptop with Windows 10. The problem with any software work around is that it does not address the root problem: core OS issues or hardware faults. Also, don't restore your registry unless you have a singularly compelling reason to do so. The registry is best managed by the OS and restore as part of a restore point or backup, not as its own discrete thing.

Comment: I get the point. I will try it out. @music2myear